# Генератор CRUD для laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Делая очередной проект, вижу очень много примерно одинаковых сущностей. Для сущности я каждый раз прохожу один и тот же этап:

- Создать модель, миграцию и контроллер (resource)
- Написать в контроллере всю логику
- Сделать верстку (чаще всего, bootstrap/semanticUI)
- - формы добавления
- - формы редактирования
- - таблицы вывода всех элементов сущности
- - подтверждения удаления

На это все уходит время. Буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь скинет ссылку на какой-либо пакет для генерации этого всего в автоматическом режиме. В идеале, чтобы это было какой-нибудь командой в консоли, но это лишь мое виденье.

Comment: клепать круды - в этом и заключается работа программиста :) Так если вы все сами делаете, в чем проблема написать такую систему самому? и она будет работать так как вам надо.

Answer (score -1):

Backpack is a collection of Laravel packages that help you build custom administration panels, for anything from presentation websites to complex web applications.

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5

Comment: Добавте основное из ссылки прямо в [тело ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/914463/edit). Приведение только ссылки ответом не является и сообщение обычно удаляется.